# C# WPF: How to check Printer Option: "Microsoft Print to PDF" is Exist

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, printing

I am a application developer.
Now. I have a problem for WPF/C# project.
Detail as follows:

I want to check existing of option:  "Microsoft Print to PDF"  in code before print a document.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEMmW.png)

If the windows environment has not ""Microsoft Print to PDF" option when printing.
I want to know: how to check this one in WPF Project.

I want the support from everybody.
Thank and best!.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [PrintServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.printserver?view=netframework-4.8) class should do it

```
var ps = new System.Printing.PrintServer();
ps.GetPrintQueues().Select(p => p.FullName).ToList();
```

Then you can just search the returned list to see if your required printer is listed